# Showing wrong message count in horneq-2.2.5 Final

Tags: jms, jmx, hornetq

I am using hornetq-2.2.5 Final. I sent 1 million messages to a queue, after that consumed all messages from the queue. When I looked through Jconsole, MessagesAdded was 1000000 and MessageCount was over 400, but no messages were in the queue. Is this a bug in hornetq-2.2.5 Final?

Answer (score 0):

there were a few bugs with 2.2.5, you should get the latest..

send us a test or a way to replicate an issue if you still hit issues